# Separar Datos Mostrados Con PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

estoy mostrando datos en una tabla atraves de un combobox, pero el problema que tengo es que las palabras estan muy pegadas, necesitan un espacio, ¿alguien me podria decir como haria eso?

[image: Aqui en la imagen estoy mostrando varios datos de la base de datos, pero como pueden ver, estos datos estan juntos ¿como los separo?]

Este Seria El codigo que llevo....

```
<?php

    include ("conexion.php");

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM basede");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.php">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">  
    </head>
    <body>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $_POST['Quimico'];?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <form method="post">    
        <select name="Quimico" id="Quimico" selected="selected">        
            <option value="" >Seleccione Una Opción</option>
            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['CAS'], $row['Concentracion'], $row['Formula'],$row['Densidad']?>"><?php echo $row['Nombre']?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>   
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Gracias, espero respuestas pronto, porfa

Comment: como deberia quedar? puedes concatenar espacios en blanco para separarlo

Answer (score 0):

La linea que tienes aquí:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['CAS'], $row['Concentracion'], $row['Formula'],$row['Densidad']?>"><?php echo $row['Nombre']?> </option>
```

La puedes cambiar poniendo espacios en blanco (o lo que quieras) entre las variables, te pongo un ejemplo (con espacios en blanco entre las variables):

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['CAS'].' '.$row['Concentracion'].' '. $row['Formula'].' '.$row['Densidad']?>"><?php echo $row['Nombre']?></option>
```

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas Gracias, y te pregunto ¿sabes alguna otra formapara mostrar esos datos asi como los estoy mostrando en diferentes cuadros de la estructura basica de una tabla? Podrias ayudarme con eso? Es que mira son varias filas las que tengo en mi base de datos, pero como lo ves hay, las estoy mostrando en un solo cuadro, ¿como separaria eso por cuadros para cada fila? Me pones ejemplo tambien porfa, Gracias

Comment: Oye nose pueden agg mas de un espacio? como agg mas?